# How to go to detail view by touch event on an image view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have created one photo slide show app with images from an array are displayed in a scroll view.
i have added touch events to it.On touching it should be the detail view of the touched image on an UIimageView
But i am not getting that by mouse click(i am running it on simulator),but i get it by alt+mouse click - at that time there are two points just as zooming on maps
I know thats the correct way,so how do i get proper touch on single mouse click?

adding the code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    int scrollWidth = 120;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,80);

    int xOffset = 0;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:0]];

    for(int index=0; index < [imagesName count]; index++)
    {
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        img.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
        img.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 160, 110);
        NSLog(@"image: %@",[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]);
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]];
        [images insertObject:img atIndex:index];



        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,110);
        [scrollView addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:index]];

        xOffset += 170;
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

     UITouch * touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

     for(int index=0;index<[images count];index++)
     {
         UIImageView *imgView = [images objectAtIndex:index];


         NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f,width=%f,height=%f",     
  imgView.frame.origin.x,imgView.frame.origin.y,
  imgView.frame.size.width,imgView.frame.size.height);
  NSLog(@"x= %f,y=%f",[touch locationInView:self.view].x,[touch      
  locationInView:self.view].y) ;


         if(CGRectContainsPoint([imgView frame], [touch locationInView:scrollView]))
         {
             [self ShowDetailView:imgView];
             break;
         }
    }
}

-(void)ShowDetailView:(UIImageView *)imgView
{
    imageView.image = imgView.image;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code better (consistently), it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of performing all the hit tests yourself in the `touchesBegan:` method, I would **highly** recomment to use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Modify your code like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...

    for(int index=0; index < [imagesName count]; index++)
    {
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        img.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
        img.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 160, 110);
        NSLog(@"image: %@",[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]);
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]];
        [images insertObject:img atIndex:index];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)]

        [img addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
        img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        /...

    }
}

- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
     UIImageView *iv = sender.view;
     [self ShowDetailView:iv];
}
```